# python libraries that provide mocked objects

Tags: python

I use python at work to develop some fairly complex libraries that have interdependencies between them. I am suggesting to my team that the developers of our internal libraries provide mocked versions of their functional classes and functions.

For an example, imagine you had an ssh class and you had to mock out ssh calls repeatedly. One way to do it would be to just mock something like ssh.run_command with different return values (using standard MagicMock). IMO a better way is to have something like

```
# mock using regexp
ssh.run_command.mock_pattern(r'ls .*', output='one two three', rc=0)
ssh.run_command.mock_pattern(r'kill \d+', output='', rc=0)
myfunc() # run a function that uses ssh somehow
ssh.run_command.assert_all_match() # assert all inputs matched a pattern
```

Basically, I am suggesting that the libraries define "helper mocks" that make it easier to write unit tests for them.

I am having trouble finding resources on this subject, or even python libraries that provide this kind of functionality -- does anyone know about this kind of tool?

Thanks!

Comment: [`mox`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiFjI2G_oLLAhUGwmMKHbEqDAAQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Fpymox%2F&usg=AFQjCNEfJdW9pkj-EZDyfoWspqWOBOzCuQ&sig2=3rzh2Hrk6EbX6HgxPJkx9g) is a mocking framework that seems to operate a bit more on the record -> playback paradigm.  In my experience, I've always been happier using `mock` than using `mox` -- but you're entitled to have your own opinion :-).

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. That looks like an interesting library, but different than my question. I am suggesting that libraries define mocked objects to help others write unit tests while using those libraries. I'm not looking for a new mocking library!